# SQL: How to get the AVG(MIN(number))?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I am looking for the **AVERAGE** (*overall*) of the **MINIMUM** number (*grouped by person*).

My table looks like this:

```
Rank    Name
1   Amy
2   Amy
3   Amy
2   Bart
1   Charlie
2   David
5   David
1   Ed
2   Frank
4   Frank
5   Frank
```

I want to know the AVERAGE of the lowest scores.  For these people, the lowest scores are:

```
Rank    Name
1   Amy
2   Bart
1   Charlie
2   David
1   Ed
2   Frank
```

Giving me a final answer of **1.5** - because three people have a MIN(Rank) of **1** and the other three have a MIN(Rank) of **2**.  That's what I'm looking for - a single number.

My real data has a couple hundred rows, so it's not terribly big.  But I can't figure out how to do this in a single, simple statement.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the set of minimum values is straightforward. The cast() is necessary to [avoid integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx) later. You could also avoid integer division by casting to float instead of decimal. (But you should be aware that floats are "useful approximations".)

```
select name, cast(min(rank) as decimal) as min_rank
from Table1
group by name
```

Now you can use the minimums as a common table expression, and select from it.

```
with minimums as (
  select name, cast(min(rank) as decimal) as min_rank
  from Table1
  group by name
)
select avg(min_rank) avg_min_rank
from minimums
```

If you happen to need to do the same thing on a platform that doesn't support common table expressions, you can a) create a view of minimums, and select from that view, or b) use the minimums as a derived table.

Comment: Ahh, this ALSO works perfectly, but slightly simpler.  Thank YOU very much too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
;WITH MinScores
AS
(
   SELECT 
     "Rank", 
     Name, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY "Rank") row_num
  FROM Table1
) 
SELECT 
  CAST(SUM("Rank") AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 
  COUNT("Rank")
FROM MinScores 
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59673/11)

Comment: PS: Update: I removed both "DISTINCT"s from your final division.  Other than that, perfection.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a derived table to get the minimums, then get the average minimum in the outer query, as in:

```
-- Get the avg min rank as a decimal
select avg(MinRank * 1.0) as AvgRank
from (
    -- Get everyone's min rank
    select min([Rank]) as MinRank
    from MyTable
    group by Name
) as a
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest one will be

for max

```
select name , max_rank = max(rank) 
from table
group by name;
```

for average

```
select name , avg_rank = avg(rank)
from table
cgroup by name;
```